# Problem with switching to 32-bit protected mode

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, boot

I am writing code for a boot loader and trying to get it to switch to 32-bit protected mode. I have tried running the code on QEMU but it's stuck with a "waiting" icon.

If I comment out the "call switch_to_pm", it boots up and prints the message "Started in 16-bit Real Mode". So switching to 32-bit protected mode seems to be the problem.

Code is as below:

*Filename*: *boot_loader.asm*

```
; Commands quick reference
; dd if=boot_loader.bin of=kernel_dev_hd0.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
; nasm -f bin -o boot_loader.bin boot_loader.asm
[BITS 16]

start:
    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288         ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph (So 07c0h + 120h = 08e0h)
    mov ss, ax          ; Stack segment is 08e0h, so segment starts at address: 0x8e00
    mov sp, 4096        ; Top of stack (ss:sp pair = 8e0h * 16 + 1000h = 9e00h)

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded the boot sector
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, MSG_REAL_MODE   ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine

    call switch_to_pm   ; Note that we never return from here.

    jmp $           ; Jump here - infinite loop!

%include "print_string.asm" 
%include "gdt.asm" 
%include "print_string_pm.asm" 
%include "switch_to_pm.asm"

[bits 32] ; Switch to 32 bit mode

; This is where we arrive after switching to and initialising protected mode. 
BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE 
    ;call print_string_pm ; Use our 32-bit print routine.
    jmp $ ; Hang.

; Global variables 
MSG_REAL_MODE db "Started in 16-bit Real Mode", 0 
MSG_PROT_MODE db "Successfully landed in 32-bit Protected Mode", 0 

; Boot sector padding
times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

*Filename*: *gdt.asm*

```
; GDT 
gdt_start:

gdt_null: ; the mandatory null descriptor 
   dd 0x0 ; ’dd’ means define double word (i.e. 4 bytes) 
   dd 0x0

gdt_code: ; the code segment descriptor 
   ; base=0x0, limit=0xfffff , 
   ; 1st flags: (present )1 (privilege )00 (descriptor type)1 -> 1001b 
   ; type flags: (code)1 (conforming )0 (readable )1 (accessed )0 -> 1010b 
   ; 2nd flags: (granularity )1 (32-bit default )1 (64-bit seg)0 (AVL)0 -> 1100b 
   dw 0xffff ; Limit (bits 0-15) 
   dw 0x0 ; Base (bits 0-15) 
   db 0x0 ; Base (bits 16 -23)
   db 10011010b ; 1st flags , type flags 
   db 11001111b ; 2nd flags , Limit (bits 16-19) 
   db 0x0 ; Base (bits 24 -31)

gdt_data: ;the data segment descriptor 
   ; Same as code segment except for the type flags: 
   ; type flags: (code)0 (expand down)0 (writable )1 (accessed )0 -> 0010b 
   dw 0xffff ; Limit (bits 0-15)
   dw 0x0 ; Base (bits 0-15) 
   db 0x0 ; Base (bits 16 -23)
   db 10010010b ; 1st flags , type flags 
   db 11001111b ; 2nd flags , Limit (bits 16-19) 
   db 0x0 ; Base (bits 24 -31) 

gdt_end: ; The reason for putting a label at the end of the 
         ; GDT is so we can have the assembler calculate 
         ; the size of the GDT for the GDT decriptor (below)

; GDT descriptior 
gdt_descriptor: 
   dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; Size of our GDT , always less one 
                              ; of the true size
   dd gdt_start ; Start address of our GDT

; Define some handy constants for the GDT segment descriptor offsets , which 
; are what segment registers must contain when in protected mode. For example , 
; when we set DS = 0x10 in PM , the CPU knows that we mean it to use the 
; segment described at offset 0x10 (i.e. 16 bytes) in our GDT , which in our 
; case is the DATA segment (0x0 -> NULL; 0x08 -> CODE; 0x10 -> DATA) 
CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start 
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

*Filename*: *switch_to_pm.asm*

```
[bits 16] 
; Switch to protected mode 
switch_to_pm:
    cli   ; We must switch off interrupts until we have 
          ; set -up the protected mode interrupt vector 
          ; otherwise interrupts will run riot.

    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; Load our global descriptor table , which defines 
                          ; the protected mode segments (e.g. for code and data)

    mov eax, cr0 ; To make the switch to protected mode , we set
    or eax, 0x1 ; the first bit of CR0, a control register
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm ; Make a far jump (i.e. to a new segment) to our 32-bit 
                         ; code. This also forces the CPU to flush its cache of 
                         ; pre -fetched and real -mode decoded instructions , which can 
                         ; cause problems.

[bits 32] 
; Initialise registers and the stack once in PM. 
init_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG ; Now in PM, our old segments are meaningless ,
    mov ds, ax       ; so we point our segment registers to the
    mov ss, ax       ; data selector we defined in our GDT
    mov es, ax 
    mov fs, ax 
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x9e00  ; Update our stack position so it is right
    mov esp, ebp     ; at the top of the free space.

    call BEGIN_PM ; Finally , call some well -known label
```

*Filename*: *print_string_pm.asm*

```
[bits 32] 
; Define some constants 
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000 
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f

; prints a null -terminated string pointed to by EDX 
print_string_pm: 
    pusha 
    mov edx , VIDEO_MEMORY ; Set edx to the start of vid mem.

print_string_pm_loop: 
    mov al, [ebx] ; Store the char at EBX in AL
    mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK ; Store the attributes in AH 

    cmp al, 0 ; if (al == 0), at end of string , so 
    je print_string_pm_done ; jump to done

    mov [edx], ax ; Store char and attributes at current 
                  ; character cell.

    add ebx , 1 ; Increment EBX to the next char in string. 
    add edx , 2 ; Move to next character cell in vid mem.

    jmp print_string_pm_loop ; loop around to print the next char.

print_string_pm_done: 
    popa 
    ret   ; Return from the function
```

*Filename*: *print_string.asm*

```
print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov ah, 0Eh         ; int 10h 'print char' function

.repeat:
    lodsb               ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0       ; If char is zero, end of string
    je .done            
    int 10h             ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat
.done:
    ret

print_character:        ; Routine: output character on to screen
    mov ah, 0Eh         ; int 10h 'print char' function
    int 10h             ; Otherwise, print it
    ret
```

Comment: `;call print_string_pm` The call to the protected mode printing is commented out. If you remove the leading semicolon, does it change anything?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think your jump into protected mode is wrong. [I wrote a bootloader](https://github.com/PrestonHager/Startaste/blob/master/bootloader.asm) once and I used `jmp 08h:init_pm` instead of `jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm`. Try changing that, it also might change depending on where your bootloader is loaded in memory, mine started at 0x7C00.

Comment: I recommend you consider this: https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?p=281389&sid=1bd884ffe9ee029a2f4215a614babffd#p281389  . I highly recommend ditching the use of segment 0x7c0. `LGDT` requires the GDT record to use a linear address(physical). Set the stack to SS:SP to 0x0000:0x7x00 (grow down from just below bootloader). Set DS to 0 (not 0x7c0). This will save you all ends of grief. Your code is likely dying because the location of the GDT you told it isn't where you think it is. When you first use a segment (like the FAR JMP to protected mode) it will fail.

Comment: What michael said; you need to patch gdt_descriptor+2 (the address) to be linear from segment relative:  mov ax,cs; shl ax, 4; add  [gdt_descriptor+2], ax.  Not sure of your assembler syntax

Comment: jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm will be the same as jmp 08h:init_pm in this code example. CODE_SEG is calculated by subtracting the start point of the GDT from the entry of the code segment descriptor. This will yield a value of 8 since the previous and first descriptor entry (the null descriptor ) takes 8 bytes.

Comment: The code is working by using the org directive (org 0x7c00) and setting ds register to 0. Regarding "LGDT requires the GDT record to use a linear address(physical).", doesn't this mean a segment descriptor entry is required in the GDT for the stack to work? When I think of a linear addressing/protected mode, I think of segment registers pointing to descriptor entries in the GDT as in this [diagram](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Memory/M77_0300_protected_mode_architecture.htm). However, it seem we still can access the stack with the SS:SP pair.